# How to use Kerberos as an authentication mechanism for API Gateway lambda authoriser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, kerberos

API Gateway in AWS supports a [number of access control mechanisms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html). One of these is a [Lambda Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html), where the API Gateway delegates the authorization decision to a lambda. That lambda uses information about the request to determine whether to provide access to the underlying API resource.

Is it possible to use Kerberos within a Lambda authorizer, i.e. to ensure only authenticated users are granted access to an API? Are there any pointers to how to implement this or examples where this has been done before, ideally in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is definitely possible to do. There's no limitation of the Lambda environment or API gateway that presents a barrier to implementing Kerberos auth.

It's a pretty simple process from the perspective of the application server performing the authentication. A quick refresher of what the kerberos auth looks like, in a nutshell:

If you receive a request without an authentication header, return a `401` status with a `WWW-Autenticate: Negotiate` header to indicate to the client they're unauthorized, but can negotiate auth via Kerberos. The client, if capable, will obtain a kerberos ticket from the KDC and request the resource again, but with an `Authorization` header containing the authorization information (ticket). The application server then validates the ticket and returns the response (with mutual auth).

As a concrete example, the `flask-kerberos` package [implements this](https://github.com/deshaw/flask-kerberos/blob/master/flask_kerberos.py) in less than 100 lines of Python (delegating much of the underlying mechanics to the python `kerberos` package, which is based largely on Apache's `mod_auth_kerb`).

As a possible alternative, you might consider having your lambda authorizer delegate the Kerberos auth to another server (say, a server running Apache with `mod_auth_kerb`) then you can mostly free your lambda function of needing to be concerned with kerberos configuration altogether.